# Truncated SAMLResponse with TCPdump

Tags: saml, tcpdump

I have been trying to use tcpdump to capture the SAML request to the server.
I am interested in the SAMLResponse so i can decoded and get the XML but tcpdump seems to truncate the output so I miss a lot of data:

> tcpdump -A -nnSs 0 'tcp port 8080 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'

This should capture all HTTP request/response/body which it does but the SAMLResponse is truncated:

> SAMLResponse=PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIElEPSJfMDAyMDg3MmQtZTlmMi00ZGU5LTkxMGYtM2NiNDc1MjVkNTk2IiBWZXJzaW9uPSIyLjAiIElzc3VlSW5zdGFudD0iMjAxOS0xMS0xM1QyMTo0ODo0Mi42ODlaIiBEZXN0aW5hdG

if I decode that I get:

> samlp:Response ID="_0020872d-e9f2-4de9-910f-3cb47525d596" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2019-11-13T21:48:42.689Z" Destinat

An incomplete output. if I add **-w /tmp/out.pcap** i am able to see the entire SAMLResponse in wireshark, what am i missing here?

I am on a linux i would like to work with this from the command line. What i dont understand is that sometimes i get more characters than others. 
I am not sure if this is in another call separate from this one if it is how to join them in tcpdump?

thanks

Comment: How are you accessing the server? I assume you have remote access like SSH?

Comment: that is correct, its a remote server.

Comment: Why not save the file and then transfer it where you can analyze with tshark/Wireshark? You could also send the raw hex of the capture over the ssh connection to your local machine which you could then read live with Wireshark.

Comment: This is very interesting, i have done port tunneling with SSH but not sure how to do this with Wireshark and TCPdump, any guide line you can point me out?

Comment: This might be useful, for someone reading this but i didnt work on my side: 

ssh root@HOST tcpdump -iany -U -s0 -w - 'not port 22' | wireshark -k -i -

Answer (score -1):

a alternative is to use `tcpflow`

```
tcpflow  -c 'port 8080'
```

Extract of `man tcpflow`

> DESCRIPTION
>          tcpflow is a program that captures data transmitted as part of TCP 
>   connections (flows), and stores the data in a way that is
>   convenient for protocol analysis or debugging.  Rather than showing
>   packet-by-packet information, tcpflow reconstructs the actual data
>   streams and stores each flow in a separate file for later analysis.

or you can use `tshark`

Comment: looks like a great solution, unfortunately I am not allow to install any package, i have to stick to tcpdump, sorry forgot to mention that. ill test it on another box for sure but i need it on that one. Thanks anywise.

Comment: The question asks for help with tcpdump. It may be relevant to post information about other programs if you can demonstrate a working example providing a SAMLResponse. Otherwise, this should be a comment, asking if OP has tried similar programs.